# Spring: How to publish a multipart/form-data request to a Rabbit Queue

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, jackson

The application has an endpoint that consumes multipart/form-data and maps it to a MultipartFile obj. From there, we attempt to upload the file to the vendor. If its successful, nothing else occurs other than a HTTP.200 series

If there is a failure, we want to publish a message to a Rabbit Queue where fields in the message include things like "endpoint", "data", "headers" so that we can consume the messages and hit the endpoint at a later date.

The problem is that I can't deserialize the MultipartFile. Ive tried using ByteArrayResource as well but get the error No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

Is there a better way to do this?

Also doing this approach because there are multiple endpoints that take in a file in different conventions, so being able to replicate the request and not have logic and just recall the endpoint is ideal

**Ultimate question:** How can I write value as string on a ByteArrayResource or MultipartFile obj with Jackson

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to save the file to disk and send the path to the queue?

In any cases, ByteArrayResource should work if you add the converter:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new 
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

Comment: I see what your saying. But the application is hosted in the cloud where there is no local file structure. We ended up just making a json message with different fields and one of them being the byte[] for the document. 

thank you for the comment